# How to change default shutdown option in Classic Shell?

Tags: windows-10, shutdown, classic-shell

Since last Windows update my computer shows the Classic Shell shutdown menu in a different order.

[image: classic shell menu]

And the "Shut down" option is not the default option. How can I modify it?

In the picture above you can see the Classic Start Menu.

Below you can see Windows 10 menu.
But the problem is not related with the menu but with the fact that when I select shutdown the default option is not "shutdown" anymore as it was some months ago.

[image]

Comment: That doesn't look like Windows 10's default Start menu. Is it some 3rd party app or something Insider Preview-specific?

Comment: @gronostaj the left side of the start menu says Insider Preview.

Comment: @gronostaj yes this is the classic start menu, but it doesn't modify the shutdown order.
I've included a screenshot of my Windows 10 menu, but the problem is not related with this but the order inside the shutdown submenu.

Answer (score 1):

- Go to *Classic Start Menu Settings*.
- Select *Show all settings*.
- On the *Customize Start Menu* tab, you can drag-and-drop items to change the order or to make submenus.

[image: Classic Start Menu configuration]

BTW, you can add additional items. Above, you can see *Awake 10 hrs*, a shortcut to a *Do Not Sleep* configuration, and *Shutdown (full, no hiberfil.sys)*, which is useful when dual booting, to allow access to the Windows partition.

Let's hope developers keep this vital tool from Ivo Beltchev functional as Windows evolves!

Comment: I've change it but when I press Alt-F4 the option that appears is  Switch user, but I don't want it.

Comment: That's not the question you posted. Alt-F4 is a *Windows* shortcut, not Classic Shell.  What is it that you want?

Comment: When you press Alt-F4 twice you get the shutdown menu. 
I want the default option on that menu to be "shutdown" and not switch user. As it was before.

Answer (score 1):

I just stumbled upon this question while searching for the very same thing, and seeing that it has no accepted answer:
Just search for "shutdown" in the Classic Shell settings. There you should be able to select any shutdown option as your default action.

Or find it in the "Main Menu" section of the settings.

[image: Searched for shutdown]